# Why can't I add a JS file to Magento?

Tags: layout, javascript

I've created a file called page.xml that contains the action method and addJs of the file.

This page.xml file is saved in /app/design/frontend/default/blank/layout and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <default>        
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>custom/progress.js</script></action>
    </reference>
  </default> 
</layout>
```

I have put the JS file in the main js folder at root under custom/progress.js

When i load the page, no JS file loads up, and I have no idea what file i need to actually edit.

Joomla is so much better at being able to add JS files, why isn't it easy in Magento?

Someone please help me! Also, it's stupid that you can't paste any code here.

Comment: Magento is different then Joomla, so no use in going into a discussion about that. The SE editor does offer a code pasting functionality in the editor designated with {} as an icon. Please paste your XML content with that extension

Comment: Hmm okay, well i've added it now. Is there no easy file just to open and edit, and manually add the JS file in (like a global header file)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Not really I gave up. I may return to it at a later date, but I ruled that there was far too much work involved for what I was trying to do

Comment: Could you please close the question by deleting, putting on hold or accepting an answer so we koop the score up? Good luck with the project!

Comment: I can't accept an answer if none of them worked.. and would have thoguht surely it would be better to always keep questions opened. It doesn't help that i've only got 1 reputation.. so i can't really do anything

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overwriting the `page.xml` I would suggest using the `layout/local.xml` file in your active template.

If it doesn't exist please create the file `app/design/frontend/default/blank/layout/local.xml` and add the `page.xml` content you've already created.

Please make sure caching and JS script compression are disabled to see the changes

Comment: This prevents my website from being shown, I jsut get a blank white page now. I deleted the layout.xml file, re-flushed all cache.. and my website still can't be shown... what has it done!?

Comment: just adding the XML file won't completely break your shop in this way. Try turning off cache.

Comment: I've flushed all cache - Magento, and CSS/JS. I've got the site working now, i removed both Page.xml and local.xml, added the local.xml back.. the site works, but nothing's changing. When I inspect the page, the new JS file isn't being loaded

Comment: If that didn't work turn the cache off. Might be a writing error

Comment: How do I turn cache off?

Comment: By the way, the location of the JS files is the js folder in root right? I've seen alot of peple talking about putting their JS files in the template folder

Comment: Hmm actually, i tried a new button 'Flush Cache Storage' and now it seems to be loading it, however there's an error in the file saying Uncaught Type Error: Cannont call method 'data' of null - that doesn't seem to mean anything

Comment: Do I need to also include jquery? or is this automatically loaded in Magento out of the box?

Comment: Please move this conversation to chat as it is too lengthy to be of value to future visitors.

Comment: I think we're going a little off scope here. try and read up on design using http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes or http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates. New errors that appear should be posted as new questions or update the existing questions with extra data

Comment: Cant move it to chat, I don't have enough 'reputation'. Helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Your inclusion of page.xml is effectively overwriting page.xml in the base/default theme. Place these changes into local.xml file or create a new module which defines a custom xml file to be included.